# How to use nsmallest with conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use nsmallest between a range in my data frame. I am trying something like this but it doesn't work at all.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'day': ['1','1','2','3','3','3'],'price': ['5','4','3','2','6','8'],'income': [20,30,40,20,40,50]})
df.loc[(df['day']>1) & (df['day']<=2) & (df.nsmallest(1,'price').index), 'income'] = 10
print(df.head())
```

The final outcome should look like:

| day | price | income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 20 |
| 1 | 4 | 30 |
| 2 | 1 | **10** |
| 2 | 4 | 20 |
| 3 | 6 | 40 |
| 3 | 8 | 50 |

So in my mind I want to retrieve the 3 nsmallest values only when the column day is equal to 2. and then make the column income in those indexes equal to 10.

Comment: Could you please add a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)), which includes the expected output.

Comment: I just updated the mre. Also, this is a simplified version. In the original one, the conditional is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your sample actually should be

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'day': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3 , 3], 'price': [5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 8], 'income': [20, 30, 40, 20, 40, 50]}
)
```

i.e. all integers, and not digit strings? (`.nsmallest()` doesn't work on strings.) If so, you could do

```
df.loc[df[df["day"] == 2].nsmallest(1, "price").index, "income"] = 10
```

to get

```
   day  price  income
0    1      5      20
1    1      4      30
2    2      3      10
3    3      2      20
4    3      6      40
5    3      8      50
```

Comment: great. It makes wonders!